# Iterate over rows, compare dates and append to list

Tags: python

Here is an example of my csv file:

```
EMPL_NO,ADRESSE,DIST_KM,DIST_MIN,DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2023-06-03
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2024-06-03
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2023-05-29
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2024-05-29
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2023-06-05
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2024-06-05
5,H4N 1P9,541,60,2026-06-05
12,H4N 1G4,503,40,2021-06-05
12,H4N 1G4,503,40,2023-06-05
```

`EMPL_NO` is my 'primary key'.

So, for every `EMPL_NO`, I need to check the corresponding dates, and I need to compare them with each other. I need to regroup them in different groups. It should regroup the values that have at most 90 days difference between them. And for the others, it should display them in another group.

For example, the expect output for the df seen above should be:

```
5, 2023-06-03, 2023-05-29, 2023-06-05
5, 2024-06-03, 2024-05-29, 2024-06-05
5, 2026-06-05
12, 2021-06-05
12, 2023-06-05
```

Can I get a little help if possible?

Comment: what did you try? where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-pandas solution:

```
import csv 
import itertools as it 
import datetime as dt 

day_range=90

with open(fn) as f_in:
    r=csv.reader(f_in)
    header=next(r)
    data=sorted([row for row in r], key=lambda x:(int(x[0]), x[-1]))
    for k,v in it.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        grp=list(v)
        for sl in grp:
            sl[-1]=dt.date(*tuple(map(int,sl[-1].split('-'))))
        while grp:
            rng=[grp.pop(0)]
            while grp and (grp[0][-1]-rng[-1][-1]).days<=day_range:
                rng.append(grp.pop(0))
            print('{}, {}'.format(k,', '.join([str(e[-1]) for e in rng])))
```

With a file of the example given, prints:

```
5, 2023-05-29, 2023-06-03, 2023-06-05
5, 2024-05-29, 2024-06-03, 2024-06-05
5, 2026-06-05
12, 2021-06-05
12, 2023-06-05
```

If you replace

```
print('{}, {}'.format(k,', '.join([str(e[-1]) for e in rng])))
```

With:

```
print('{}: {}'.format(k,'; '.join(["({})".format(", ".join(map(str, e[1:]))) for e in rng])))
```

Prints:

```
5: (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2023-05-29); (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2023-06-03); (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2023-06-05)
5: (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2024-05-29); (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2024-06-03); (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2024-06-05)
5: (H4N 1P9, 541, 60, 2026-06-05)
12: (H4N 1G4, 503, 40, 2021-06-05)
12: (H4N 1G4, 503, 40, 2023-06-05)
```

Here is the same thing in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools as it 

day_range=90

data=pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=['DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION'])

data.sort_values(by=['EMPL_NO', 'DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION'],inplace=True)

data['group']=(data['DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION'].diff() 
                > pd.Timedelta(days=day_range)).cumsum()

for k,v in it.groupby(data.iterrows(),
            key=lambda row: (row[1]['EMPL_NO'], row[1]['group'])):
    row=', '.join([str(row[1]['DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION'].date()) for row in v])
    print('{}, {}'.format(k[0],row))
# same output
```

If you want to add fields to the output, you would do it in the last line of each of these.

Comment: just perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: is it possible to also display 'ADRESSE', 'DIST_KM', 'DIST_MIN' in the output?

Comment: "you would do it in the last line of each of these." Which line? Thank you again so much.

Comment: You would add fields here: `[str(e[-1]) for e in rng]` or here: `[str(row[1]['DATE_INTERNE_INSPECTION'].date()) for row in v]`

Comment: Can you show me how?... Sorry for asking too much

Comment: I don't know what output you want is the issue. Try it! It is not hard

Comment: I just want to display 'ADRESSE', 'DIST_KM', 'DIST_MIN' also (columns in original post). I tried.. But I just don't understand the logic

Comment: Try using `print('{}, {}'.format(k,', '.join([str((e[1],e[2],e[3],str(e[-1]))) for e in rng])))`

Comment: It worked, but it copies the name and all the info each time it want to display a date. Only 'EMPL_NO' print once as it should !

Comment: Example of new output: 760, ('110 RUE LAFONTAINE EAST ANGUS QC', '185', '1 heure 59 mins', '2022-12-17'), ('110 RUE LAFONTAINE EAST ANGUS QC', '185', '1 heure 59 mins', '2022-10-17')